# Storing global immutable data in static classes

Tags: c#, .net, static, global, application-design

I have a WinForms project, which uses a lot of user controls. Some of these user controls use classes from business logic layer. These classes are mainly performing CRUD operation to a database (through data access layer) plus some additional validation and reporting.

The project uses some common objects (logged user, some controllers and validators), which are instantiated in main form and then injected into child user controls via initialization methods or public properties. This means, that I have a lot of code, which just passes these common objects from parent control to child controls.

In order to avoid this, I could create a static class (ApplicationContext for example) and save all common controls into it. This would happen in the main form and all other user controls or forms in the project could use it.

I see that this pattern is discouraged in general (storing some global data in static classes). But what if this data is immutable? Is this approach ever a good idea?

Or do you know any other approach, which could help me get rid of all the initialization code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [Inversion of Control](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) container like [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) or [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) and have it automatically wire up your object graph for you.

You can have each object that requires any one of the common objects define a dependency to their interfaces, either though a constructor argument, or as a public property, and the IoC container will wire the appropriate objects together.

Property injection example with Unity:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl 
{
    [Dependency]
    public LoggedUserService UserService { get; set; }

    public void Method()
    {
        // the IoC container will ensure that the UserService
        // property has been set to an object
    }
}
```

All you do in the main form is registering the common objects you want the IoC container to know about and then you ask for the root object. The object graph will be assembled magically for you and you don't have to to all the wire code nor care how it is done.

Comment: IoC container was what I was looking for, thanks. I chose ninject :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dependency injection / ioc container for maintaining your global objects.
I have made good experience with the [autofac library](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) but there are many other available.
When using setter injection, all of your controls get set dependent objects set automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Singletons for this situation.  Singletons will allow you to use the same instance of your object, more safe and flexible than static.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    public object Property1 {get;set;}
    public void Method1 (){}

    static Singleton instance = null;
    static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance==null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

then you can use it like you would static, but a bit different...

```
public class Main
{
     public Main()
     {
         Singleton.Instance.Property1 = "somevalue";
         Singleton.Instance.Method1();
     }

}
```

Comment: Singletons are bad when they are not immutable. Global state that can be changed any time is a source of bugs that are very hard to tackle.

Comment: You're right, if he's changing the objects rather than just accessing them.  However, I understood that he was setting them up in Main, and to avoid passing these unchanged instances around, he could use Singletons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static class to store some immutable data - no problem with this.
How ever if you want to store controls there it might not work as expected. 
For example method like OnDataBinding and Render.